# Magento varnish user-agent issue

Tags: magento-1.7, cache, varnish, turpentine

I'm currently running Magento 1.7 with Varnish Turpentine.

I have noticed a strange behavior on cached content - Varnish returns same content for mobile and tablet(iPad), although in Magento back-end I have set design exceptions for matched expressions (iPad should use default, mobiles use mobi) and it works like a charm until varnish default.vcl is applied.

After checking around I found out that varnish use device detection and normalizes user-agent as per following:

```
if (req.http.User-Agent ~ "iP(?:hone|ad|od)|BlackBerry|Palm|Googlebot-Mobile|Mobile|mobile|mobi|Windows Mobile|Safari Mobile|Android|Opera (?:Mini|Mobi)") {
set req.http.X-Normalized-User-Agent = "mobile";
```

Well, fair enough... clearly mobiles and tablets will return same cache hit as both are normalized as mobile ... lets separate iPad I though

```
if (req.http.User-Agent ~ "iP(?:hone|od)|BlackBerry|Palm|Googlebot-Mobile|Mobile|mobile|mobi|Windows Mobile|Safari Mobile|Android|Opera (?:Mini|Mobi)") {
set req.http.X-Normalized-User-Agent = "mobile";
else if (req.http.User-Agent ~ "iPad") {
set req.http.X-Normalized-User-Agent = "ipad";
```

A big surprise after this change was that varnish still returns same cached content.

I have tried to use different varnish device-detects but all unfortunately failed.

Have anybody has a smallest clue what could be the issue?

Comment: After you made the change to separate iPad, did you apply those VCL changes to the running instance of Varnish?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your time helping to sort this out.

Yes, I did apply changes to running instance, also I tried to restart varnish on the server and applied changes on running instance afterwards but both returned same issue.

Comment: Ok, perhaps try turning off the *Normalize User-Agent* option in Turpentine as a test and see if that works?

Comment: Hi, once Normalize User-Agent option is turned off, cache serves one content for all devices (even if I apply new config). Also I noticed that if Normalize User-Agent option is on and I delete all entries regarding device detection and apply it, cache still serves different content for mobile agent and pc agent.

Answer (score 0):

Without hashing, it won't change the content, please check below, it will help

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.http.User-Agent ~ "iP(?:hone|od)|BlackBerry|Palm|Googlebot-Mobile|Mobile|mobile|mobi|Windows Mobile|Safari Mobile|Android|Opera (?:Mini|Mobi)") {
        set req.http.X-Normalized-User-Agent = "mobile";
    } 
    else if (req.http.User-Agent ~ "iPad") {
       set req.http.X-Normalized-User-Agent = "ipad";
    else {
       set req.http.X-Device = "other";
    }
}

sub vcl_hash {
    if (req.X-Normalized-User-Agent) {
       hash_data(req.X-Normalized-User-Agent);
    }
}

sub vcl_deliver {    
    set resp.http.X-Varnish-Device = req.X-Normalized-User-Agent;
}
```

Will definitely recommend to use [devicedetect.vcl](https://github.com/varnishcache/varnish-devicedetect/blob/master/devicedetect.vcl) instead of relying on user agent.